# To analyse CPU consumption of Firefox addons in SO

Tags: debugging, firefox, cpu, add-on

I currently analyse inefficient Firefox addons by uninstalling them and seeing empirically in a long run whether the addon was a problem or not. However, this way of finding the inefficient addons is very time-consuming.

I would like to know exact numerical ways to see

1. the CPU consumption for each addon independently in Firefox
2. the CPU consumption for two different addons at the same time in Firefox (*note that it is not practical to have two addons in your browser at each time and then measure the need in a long term*)

It is apparently enough to measure only CPU, not memory consumption at all, to keep tests simple.

**Is there any tool to measure CPU consumption for the combination of 2 in a set of addons?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, unfortunately there is no such tool. The closest thing are various profiling tools (like Venkman), which can show you time spent in various JS functions, but aggregating that data to determine if an extension is inefficient will be tricky.

Mozilla also uses dtrace on Mac (with special builds of Firefox and special dtrace scripts) to analyze performance. I imagine it could be adapted for this too.

Comment: Now in Firefox 94 there is such a tool: `about:performance` can show you CPU (Energy Impact) and Memory usage for all tabs and addons. And `about:memory` will allow you to make recordings of processes' statistics, then you can filter it by process id.

Answer (score 0):

There is a Firefox add-on to see the *memory* usage: [about addons memory](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/about-addons-memory/).

Install the addon and open the page `about:addons-memory`, it will display the memory usage for all installed addon (including Firefox native addons).

You might also be interested by [tab memory usage](https://addons.mozilla.org/fr/firefox/addon/tab-memory-usage/), which display memory usage for each opened tab.